# Can I get tracks without authorization?

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

Is it possible to get tracks from open group without authorization?
I'm using PHP api and i found solution here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/soundcloudapi/XfxvE2P6P0c
But it does not work.

As i saw JS Api can do it.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Upload my class:
http://pastebin.com/xg6Y5rsR

Use:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  Url soundcloud: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form> 

<?php

if($_POST['fname']){

include("class.soundcloud.php");
$sCloud = new soundCloud();

$filename = $sCloud->exploserChaine($_POST['fname']);
$link = $sCloud->exploserChaine($sCloud->getMp3($_POST['fname']));


if(!$link)
    echo("No links !");

else
    echo ('<a href="http://media.soundcloud.com/stream/'.$link['5'].'?stream_token=Own3d">Download '.$filename['5'].'.mp3</a>');
 }
```

Have fun ;)